# Prevent exiting scheduled task

Tags: java, timer

I have java console application what will run as daemon where I want to use Timer.schedule to execute task every n seconds.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(true);
timer.schedule(new ATask(), 0,10000);   
//insert block here
```

What is the best way to "block" from exiting?

Answer (score 1):

try `Thread#join()` your current Thread.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(true);
timer.schedule(new ATask(), 0,10000); 
Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
currentThread.join();
```

Comment: I don't want to terminate, I need a block otherwise program exits right after timer.schedule()...

Comment: there is still a problem, if I call timer.cancel(), timer stops but main thread is stuck